# raggedright text writes over wrapfigure in a parbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, wrapfigure, parbox

I want to have a parbox with an image in the top right corner and text floating around it. Using \wrapfigure, this works well. However, this doesn't seem to work with \raggedright, as the text simply writes over the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}

\fbox{\parbox[c][36mm][c]{57mm}{
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{30pt}
\framebox(30,30){}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
}}

\vspace{10mm}

\fbox{\parbox[c][36mm][c]{57mm}{
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{30pt}
\framebox(30,30){}
\end{wrapfigure}
\raggedright{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
}}

\end{document}
```

[image: boxes]

Any idea what causes this and how I can avoid it? Using \RaggedRight from the ragged2e package doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\raggedright` does not take an argument so your extra `{}` formed a group which breaks `wrapfig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}

\fbox{\parbox[c][36mm][c]{57mm}{
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{30pt}
\framebox(30,30){}
\end{wrapfigure}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
}}

\vspace{10mm}

\fbox{\parbox[c][36mm][c]{57mm}{
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{30pt}
\framebox(30,30){}
\end{wrapfigure}
\raggedright
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
}}
\end{document}
```